# filterByFormula Result to Create New Record

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, airtable

I’m using Twilio Functions (node.js) to load to AirTable all incoming texts. I’m utilizing 2 tables -

- “Receive Text” with columns "Inbound Text Date", "Inbound Text Content" and "UID".
- “Users” with columns "UID" and Phone Number ("Your Number").

When a text comes in, all I have is the phone number. so I’m trying to use FilterByFormula with the phone number to retrieve the user’s UID from the “Users” table.

Here’s the code I’m running -

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

    var Airtable = require('airtable');
    var base = new Airtable({apiKey: context.AIRTABLE_API_KEY}).base('app######');


    var phone = event.From;
    var format_phone = // format to +1 (###) ###-####

    base('Users').select({
        filterByFormula: `Your Number = "${format_phone}"`,
        view: "Grid view"
    }).eachPage(function page(records, fetchNextPage) {
        records.forEach(function(record) {
            console.log(record.id);
        });
        fetchNextPage();
    }, function done(err) {
        if (err) { console.error(err); return; }
    });

    inputbase = 'Receive Text';
    message = {
        'UID' : ['rec#######'],
        'Inbound Text Date' : Date.now(),
        'Inbound Text Content' : event.Body,
    };

    base(inputbase).create(message, function(err, record) {
      if (err) { console.error(err); return; }
      console.log(record.getId());
      callback(null, message);
    });

};
```

Right now for testing, the UID is hardcoded and it's working fine.  I'm unsure how do I get the UID from the filterByFormula into a variable or just straight into the message variable.

Both the UID and Phone Number are unique values in “Users”, so I don't expect to receive more than 1 record back.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, let me know how it goes.

```
    const Airtable = require('airtable');

    exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

    const base = new Airtable({apiKey: context.AIRTABLE_API_KEY}).base(context.AIRTABLE_DATABASE);

    const phone = event.From;
    const body = event.Body;

    function createRecord(UID) {
        const today = new Date();
        const date = `${(today.getMonth()+1)}/${today.getDate()}/${today.getFullYear()}`;

        const inputbase = 'Receive Text';

        const message = {
            'UID': UID,
            'Inbound Text Date': date,
            'Inbound Text Content': body,
        };

        base(inputbase).create(message, function(err, record) {
        if (err) { 
            console.error(err);
            callback("error");
            }
            console.log(record.getId());
            callback(null, message);
         });
    }


    base('Users').select({
        filterByFormula: `{Your Number} = "${phone}"`,
        view: "Grid view"
    }).firstPage().then(records => {
        if (!records[0]) {
            console.log("**NO MATCH**");
            createRecord("**NO MATCH**");
        } else {
            console.log("**MATCH**");
            createRecord(records[0].fields.UID);
          }
        })
    .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            callback("error");
    });
};
```

Comment: that worked perfectly, thanks!

Just a few changes I made if anyone uses this for AirTable in the future -

 1. In order to reference the UID in the "Users" table and connect the two records, I needed the "rec#" number and not the actual UID number. Instead of `records[0].fields.UID` (returns _the content_ of the UID)  I used `records[0].id` (returns the "rec#" number).

 2. For some reason, AirTable requires the "rec#" to be entered as an array, so instead of `'UID': UID` I entererd `'UID': [UID]`